# Overwrite existing data with zeroes?

Tags: windows, lubuntu

Okay so I'm trying to format my hdd to ntfs on Ubuntu 13.04  and it gives me two options, Don't overwrite existing data(Quick), and Overwrite existing data with zeroes(Slow). What does it mean to overwrite the existing data with zeroes? I plan on installing windows 7 but it says my  hdd must be in NTFS format. Please help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `quick` option, and should be work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The overwrite with 0's will literally write #FFFFFF to every sector on the harddrive, permanently erasing the data that was there.  This is a technique used to remove all data fragments which might be left on the drive.  It's usually used when pernicious malware is expected or as part of a data-wipe routine.

Chances are, you just need the quick option.

Comment: In fact, to complete erase the data you'd have to overwrite it with zeroes several times or overwrite with randoms. For the rest I agree.

Comment: @Private - Great extension, and yea most do several passes to ensure the wipe.

Comment: Thanks so much you guys! Much appreciated! Will come back to say how everything goes, who knows who else might be wondering about this.

Comment: @user184529  Please accept the answer if you're satisfied with the response :]

Comment: t didn't work i still get a message saying "Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. Windows must be installed to a partition formatted as NTFS. The partition is of an unrecognized type"

Comment: Did you try removing all the partitions and allowing Win8 Installer to do his work? It uses to be automatically formatted if there is no partitions.

Comment: How do i do remove all the partitions exactly? I'm getting really fed up with Ubuntu >< is there anyone here that requires the whole story to help me because I'm really starting to get annoyed and would do anything to just go back to using windows..

Answer (score 2):

If it is SSD, you only need to overwrite it once for security since it is not magnetic. Overwriting it several times is bad for SSD's. Also, use MBR then NTFS if you plan to install windows. Regards.